# meda error $dato=$d['id']; dice que ahi esta el error por el id que hago

Tags: php

```
<?php


$rr = new Consultas();
$rx = Consultas::getRepeated($_POST["id_paciente"],$_POST["id_medico"],$_POST["fecha"],$_POST["hora"]);
if($rx==null){
$c= new Con_Servicios();
$r = new Consultas();
$r->nota = $_POST["nota"];
$r->id_paciente = $_POST["id_paciente"];
$r->id_medico = $_POST["id_medico"];
$r->fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$r->hora = $_POST["hora"];
$r->user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$r->id_pago = $_POST["id_pago"];
$r->monto = $_POST["monto"];
$r->diagnostico = $_POST["diagnostico"];
$r->sintomas = $_POST["sintomas"];
$r->medicamentos = $_POST["medicamentos"];
$r->add();
Core::alert(" Se Agrego la Consulta exitosamente!");

$rr = $r->UltimoId();
foreach ( $rr as $Fila ) {
    $d= $Fila;
}
$dato=$d['id'];

if($_POST['id_servicio'] != "" )
{
    if (is_array($_POST['id_servicio'])) 
    {

        while(list($key,$value) = each($_POST['id_servicio']))
        {   $c->id_consulta=$dato;
            $c->id_servicio=$value;
            $c->add();
//$sql=mysqli_query("insert into con_servicios(id_consulta,id_servicio,creado) values ('22','5','18-06-12 10:34:09 AM')");
        }
    }
}

Core::alert("Agregado exitosamente!");
}else{
Core::alert("Error al agregar, Consulta Repetida!");
}
//Core::redir("./index.php?view=consultas");
?>
```

Comment: hola ricardo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para que la pregunta sea de mayor calidad has de explicar mejor el error que tienes y lo que has intentado para resolverlo. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Las asignaciones que haces en tu código son muy extrañas: `$r->nota = $_POST["nota"];` y todas las demás. ¿El objeto `$r` tiene las propiedades como  `nota` declaradas como `public`  e intentas cambiarlas de ese modo? ¿Por qué no pasas esa propiedades en el constructor mejor: `$r = new Consultas();` el estilo que estarías implementando no encapsula tu objeto si se puede modificar una propiedad así. Sería bueno que expliques un poco lo que hace tu programa. Y, cuando un código de error, di cuál es el error que da.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en el bucle estas iterando un objeto no un array

Intenta cambiar por esto

```
$rr = $r->UltimoId();
foreach ( $rr as $Fila ) {
    $d= $Fila->id;
}
$dato=$d;
```